# How to configure crawler extension to exclude hidden fields from tt_news?

Tags: web-crawler, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I use this config for my crawler config for tt_news:

```
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets {
    items = &tx_ttnews[tt_news]=[_TABLE:tt_news;_PID:6;]
    items {
        baseUrl = http://www.example.com
        cHash = 1
        procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex
    }
}
```

Resulting the crawler to index also hidden news entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the config with a where clause:

```
tx_crawler.crawlerCfg.paramSets {
        items = &tx_ttnews[tt_news]=[_TABLE:tt_news;_PID:6;_WHERE: and hidden = 0]
        items {
            baseUrl = http://www.example.com
            cHash = 1
            procInstrFilter = tx_indexedsearch_reindex
        }
   }
```

Now all the records with hidden = 1 are not crawled. Its not documented, but in the source:

https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/crawler/blob/master/class.tx_crawler_lib.php#L752